# Loading and using a JS module in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, puppeteer

I'm building an npm package for internal use. One of it's functions is DOM parsing so I need to load it inside a browser. I would like to use puppeteer for testing.

In the docs, I've found `page.injectFile()` to use for local JS files. However, my file is a module (file I'm injecting is already transpiled to regular JavaScript) and I don't know what to do after injecting it into a puppeteer's browser page.

My code so far:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.injectFile('../build/MyModule')
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .then(error => console.log(error));
})();
```

I get an `error`, `ReferenceError: require is not defined` because I'm using require in `MyModule`.
Can I even use JS modules like this in puppeteer and if yes, what's the corret way to get an instance of `MyModule` and use it?

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt puppeteer can achieve this since it is just a nodejs driver for headless chrome.

If you need to use custom module with cmd `require(...)` inside, you would probably need to use module bundler like `webpack` to generate a bundle file with all the dependencies, then `inject` into puppeteer page.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I know I came late to the party but I am trying to use `browserify` to generate a bundle of dependencies and inject into my puppeteer page. Any thoughts on how inject these dependencies? I've been trying `page.addScriptTag()` but getting nowhere... thank you